# org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory Destroy method on bean with name 'applicationResource' threw llegalStateException

Tags: spring, jpa

This really drove me crazy, Here is the software stack I'm using for my current project.
Jersey(Rest layer), Spring jdbc mixed with Spring jpa data, everything works well until I shut down tomcat. I see below message on the console:

```
2013-12-07 19:40:55,760 ERROR org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory(ln513) - Destroy method on bean with name 'applicationResource' threw an exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.ThreadLocalHttpContext.getRequest(ThreadLocalHttpContext.java:82)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$2.invoke(WebApplicationImpl.java:286)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy53.hashCode(Unknown Source)
    at com.my.resource.BaseResource.hashCode(BaseResource.java)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.hash(ConcurrentHashMap.java:333)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.remove(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1175)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeDestruction(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:357)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:220)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:486)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:740)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:455)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1090)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1064)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1010)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:558)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4831)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5478)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
2013-12-07 19:40:55,761 INFO org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean(ln441) - Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'myEntity'
```

When I used pure jdbc, I didn't see this error, I know this error started to crawl off after introducing jpa, and The error was thrown when PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeDestruction(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:357) was called.

My dao.xml setting

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
      p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
      destroy-method="close" p:driverClass="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
      p:password="${jdbc.password}" p:jdbcUrl="${jdbc.url}" p:user="${jdbc.username}"
      p:initialPoolSize="10" p:minPoolSize="10" p:maxPoolSize="50"/>

<bean id="nameParameterJdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate"
      c:dataSource-ref="dataSource"/>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="com.mycompany.hibernate.config.HibernateExtendedJpaDialect"/>
    </property>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myEntity"/>
</bean>

<jpa:repositories base-package="com.mycompany.repository"/>
```

All of my Jersey Resources are annotated with @Component.

Can you guys see what went wrong?

Thanks, I appreciate your time.

Paul